# Editing Checkout Page - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, billing

I need to change a couple headings in the /checkout page on my wordpress, woo commerce website. The screenshot below is my current checkout page. The text highlighted in red is what needs to be changed. I've looked in the  form-checkout.php but nothing shouts out at me to change.

[image]

I'd be grateful for any input,

Thanks

Comment: Blank Attempt : Search for your text all the files and tables your have !

Comment: Blank attempt? @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: Just to search over all. You got it ?

Comment: Sorry, where am I searching and what am I searching for? Please could you elaborate? Thanks @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: The Text you wanted to search and replace.

Comment: You wanted the highlighted text and replace with your own text isn't it ?

Comment: Next time, please add the image directly to the post.